# I'm Blue, Da ba dee da ba die

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, color

Write a program, which outputs `I'm Blue,`  and then `Da, Ba, Dee, Da, Ba, Die,`  forever, **the words must be space-seperated in one line, and it must pause 0.4 to 0.6 seconds after printing each word.** Also, the text should be outputted in the color blue 0x0000FF or in ANSI escape code blues.

So the output must be something like this:
[image]

You can use any programming language you want.
The output can be in either text or image form (escape codes allowed!).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest program in bytes wins!

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) and nice first question! For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main. You might want to allow some lenience with the 0.5s (0.45s to 0.55s or something). Also, should it pause between "I'm" and "Blue"?

Comment: Also, can we use 4-bit [ANSI escape code blues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) which aren't exactly #0000FF, or do we have to use 8-bit or truecolour? (context: Many answers will print the output to a terminal)

Comment: How exact or reproducible does the half second need to be? Can I find some arithmetic operation that takes 0.5s on my machine and use that for delay?

Comment: Yes, you can. And you must pause between I'm and Blue. And I've edited it so it can be 0.4-0.6s.

Comment: Should the words be space-separated, or could each word optionally be on its own line?

Comment: +1 to Kevin's question - I'm guessing that the requirement "without any trailing newlines" is actually talking about when we print a word we cannot print a newline, rather than saying that after "forever" has passed we can't print a newline (unobservable) - but clarity would be good.

Comment: Since I expect many answers will create the 0.4-0.6 second delay via a long computation, is it OK if it takes that long on my machine but maybe take a different length of time on a slower/faster machine?

Comment: Your challenge and the tags contradict eachother. You say it has to generate a specific output, but that output has to run forever. Therefore, the output is always changing. The question has [tag:kolmogorov-complexity], which requires a constant output. I don't think this challenge matches that tag, as the *whole* output is never constant. If I'm wrong, please ignore me.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>46</s> 45 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
27ç"ÿ[34mI'm"?…žå°êèÞ#5∍'—ÇªÞ'‡—š',«™1úε₄;.W?
```

Uses an ANSI escape code to print in blue ([which is `rgb(0,55,218)` in Windows 10 by default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) - see screenshot below - but could be changed to the required `rgb(0,0,255)` in the console properties itself if necessary).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AVgAp/9vc2FiaWX//zI3w6ciw79bMzRtSSdtIj/igKbFvsOlwrDDqsOow54jNeKIjSfigJTDh8Kqw54n4oCh4oCUxaEnLMKr4oSiMcO6zrU/////LS1uby1sYXp5) (with the sleep `₄;.W` removed).

*Screenshot:*
[image]

**Explanation:**

```python
27ç             # Push 27, and convert it to a character with this codepoint: <ESC>
   "ÿ[34mI'm"   # Push this string, where `ÿ` is filled with the earlier <ESC> character
             ?  # Pop and print it (without newline)
…žå°êèÞ         # Push dictionary string "da ba dee"
       #        # Split it on spaces: ["da","ba","dee"]
        5∍      # Extend it to size 5: ["da","ba","dee","da","ba"]
          '—Ç  '# Push dictionary string "die"
             ª  # Append it to the list: ["da","ba","dee","da","ba","die"]
Þ               # Cycle this list indefinitely:
                #  ["da","ba","dee","da","ba","die","da","ba","dee","da",...]
 '‡—           '# Push dictionary string "blue"
    š           # Prepend it in front of the infinite list
     ',«       '# Append a comma to each string
        ™       # Titlecase each word
         1ú     # Prepend a leading space to each string
ε               # Foreach over the list:
 ₄;             #  Push 500 (push 1000 and halve it)
   .W           #  Pop and sleep that many millisecond
     ?          #  Print the string (without newline)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `…žå°êèÞ` is `"da ba dee"`; `'—Ç` is `"die"`; and `'‡—` is `"blue"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But you can save one byte by using `”` for titlecased dictionary-compressed strings

Comment: @HelloWorld Unfortunately not, since `”` uses both an opening and closing quote, so `…žå°êèÞ`, `'—Ç`, and `'‡—` would all three become `”žå°êèÞ”`/`”—Ç”`/`”‡—”`, making it +3 bytes to save the -1 byte of `™`. :)

Answer (score 2):

## HTML + JavaScript (All Browsers), <s>30 + 77 = 107</s> <s>24 + 90 = 114</s> 24 + 87 = 111 bytes

```js
i=5
setInterval(a=>b.append("Da0Ba0Dee0Da0Ba0Die0Blue".split(0)[(i<6)+i++%6]+", "),500)
```

```html
<body id=b text=blue>I'm
```

---

+7 because the original code didn't match the spec.
-3 from @jdt for using `.append(...)` instead of `.innerHTML+=...`

Comment: It looks like your cycle is starting on "Ba" in the snippet, should be an easy fix

Comment: @xnor Hm, it's working for me; what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome on Windows

Comment: The issue is that the code depends on the number of calls to `setInterval`/`setTimeout` and how the browser assigns them IDs. It seems that in this context, on Firefox / Chrome (?) it always starts at 3, and in Brave it starts at 8 (???), but I don't know if I can rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

## HTML + JavaScript, <s>22</s> 18 + <s>90</s> <s>89</s> <s>88</s> 86 = 104 bytes

```js
setInterval("b.append(`${'Da Ba Dee Da Ba Die Blue'.split` `[i++%7]}, `);i%=6",i=419)
```

```html
<a href=# id=b>I'm
```

-6 bytes: use `.append()` instead of `.before()`, use `setInterval` string eval (from [@jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251878/im-blue-da-ba-dee-da-ba-die/251997?noredirect=1#comment561319_251997))

Comment: There was a stray ` character at the end of your javascript.

Comment: And since the link has been visited, the text is now coming out in purple :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 135 bytes

```python
import time
def f(l):[print(end=i+' ')==time.sleep(.5)for i in l.split()]
f("\033[34mI'm Blue,")
while 1:f("Da, Ba, Dee, Da, Ba, Die,")
```

Works on Windows Command Prompt

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYqxCsMgFEV3v@KRRaVBWmyXgEvI0m9IOxTyJA@eRoyl9OutGTqcC4d70resW7S1UkhbLlAooFjQg1eshzllikVhXBydJEjt3BGYnRGTMjfttwwEFIHNnpiK0k/hVfc4Wzvba7jLACO/se@0@KzECJeh3dOrh7ExIbb5Cx1ZrT8)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 145 bytes

```python
import time
def f(l):[print(end=i+' ',flush=1)==time.sleep(.5)for i in l.split()]
f("\033[1;34mI'm Blue,")
while 1:f("Da, Ba, Dee, Da, Ba, Die,")
```

Works on MacOS iTerm

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncq9CoMwFIbh3as4uJjQIJW0i5JFXHoNtkPBEzxw8oNGSq8@jUOH74UPnvhNa/A6Z3IxbAkSOawWtGAFy36OG/kk0C@GLg00yvKxr6aTxpyw3RkxivYubdiAgDxwu0emJOSrsqJ@XrWeu0Hf3KNxMPKBqpbVZyVG6PoCpreCsWxCLPkfOlnOPw)

-8 thanks to 97.100.97.109

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 196 bytes

```python
from time import*;from itertools import*
p=print;s=sleep
p(end="\033[1;33mI'm ",flush=1);s(.5)
p(end="Blue, ",flush=1)
for i in cycle(['Da','Ba','Dee','Da','Ba','Die']):s(.5);p(end=i+', ',flush=1)
```

Works on MacOS iTerm

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYy7CoMwFIZ3nyK4HG1DqYQuDVnEpc9gOxR7xAO5kcTBp0/RYtvlg//C55c0OStyHoMzLJFBRsa7kA5yayhhSM7puNeFVz6QTTKqqBF94Su0L1Xez0L0jRTC3MCwko96jpNqahmr06XeX62ekf@txegCI0aWDcugseqhewKHdkWHuPKXCeFRXzef/PjoCJzB15bzGw)

---

Note: on TIO, colours aren't shown, and everything gets shown when the program finishes. Here is a video of this running on another editor:

[image: Output]

Comment: I have an answer that uses a 3rd party library and is 40 bytes shorter, waiting to see if you can outgolf me!

Comment: Now it’s 29 bytes shorter

Comment: @py3programmer - 24 bytes shorter than yours, no 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Just reduced mine by 4 bytes, will golf when I have more time.

Comment: @py3programmer, I don't think yours outputs a comma between "Da", "Ba", etc.

Comment: My bad, just fixed it. Bytes are stuck at 177 now

Comment: And by the way, your code outputs `←[1;34mI'm Blue, Da, Ba, Dee, Da, Ba, Die, Da, Ba, Dee, Da, Ba, Die, Da, Ba, Dee, Da, Ba, Die, Da, Ba, Dee, Da, Ba, Die, Da, Ba, Dee, Da, Ba...` with no color in my terminal. Is it something wrong with my terminal or your code?

Comment: @py3programmer - works fine on my computer.

Comment: Which terminal are you using? Mine is Command Prompt.

Comment: I'm using iTerm on Mac.

Comment: Does my code work on yours?

Comment: @py3programmer yes it does

Comment: Well, I guess you'll have to add some kind of initializer to make this code work on Windows. Mine does, and that's where `colorama` comes in. When I added my `colorama` initializing code to your answer, it works in my terminal. Without it your code fails, though.

Comment: This is mainly a Windows issue, other platforms it should work fine.

Comment: [145 bytes?](https://tio.run/##Ncq9CoMwFIbh3as4uJjQIJW0i5JFXHoNtkPBEzxw8oNGSq8@jUOH74UPnvhNa/A6Z3IxbAkSOawWtGAFy36OG/kk0C@GLg00yvKxr6aTxpyw3RkxivYubdiAgDxwu0emJOSrsqJ@XrWeu0Hf3KNxMPKBqpbVZyVG6PoCpreCsWxCLPkfOlnOPw)

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252185/110681) version that works on your system, but fails on non-Windows platforms.</a>

Comment: Now its -4 bytes shorter

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 + `colorama`, <s>177 176 175 167 166 162</s> 160 bytes

I used `colorama` when I was interested in coloring `stdout`, and it certainly should help here!

(Also used because The Thonnu's answer was really long)

```python
import colorama,time;colorama.init()
def m(n):[print(end=i+" ")==time.sleep(.5)for i in n.split()]
m("\033[34mI'm Blue,")
while 1:m("Da, Ba, Dee, Da, Ba, Die,")
```

### How to use:

As The Thonnu pointed out, this program fails on TIO, so to execute it:

1. Download IDLE (if you don't have it)
2. Open your terminal
3. Type `py -m pip install colorama`
4. Create a new file
5. Copy the code
6. Save it (here it will be `colored.py`)
7. Type `py -m colored` (or whatever you saved the file as without the `py` part) on your terminal.

See [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17eD0IX4a7n7kdBvdq2wSAyRqQnxLiy0C/view?usp=sharing) that shows it being done.

### Direct downloading version, 223 bytes:

Will download `colorama` from pip and executes.

```python
import os,time
os.system("py -mpip install colorama")
import colorama;colorama.init
m=lambda n:print(end="\033[34m"+n)or time.sleep(.5)
m("I'm ");m("Blue, ")
while 1:
    for i in['Da','Ba','Dee','Da','Ba','Die']:m(i+", ");
```

### Non-Windows version, 135 bytes:

On windows platforms, Colorama is required for initializing the terminal. Other ones, don't think so.

```python
import time
def m(n):[print(end=i+' ')==time.sleep(.5)for i in n.split()]
m("\033[34mI'm Blue,")
while 1:m("Da, Ba, Dee, Da, Ba, Die,")
```

Comment: I don't think that works, because you need the `flush=1` in `print` if you use it in combination with `time.sleep` If you don't have that, nothing will print.

Comment: It does work for me.

Comment: I'm using CMD prompt

Comment: Ok, then on your computer, I can take 8 bytes off my answer, making it 4 bytes shorter than yours.

Comment: Doesn't matter; now my code's on a tie.

Comment: [-2 bytes](/a/252001)

Comment: That code still requires an initializer; it handles the ANSI escape code as plain text on Windows CMD.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 148 bytes

```
@set/p=␛[94mI'm <nul
@call:c Blue
:l
@for %%i in (Da Ba Dee Da Ba Die) do @call:c %%i
@goto l
:c
@ping 192.512 -n 1 -w 500>nul
@set/p=%1, <nul
```

Note: `␛` represents the Escape character (`^[`). Explanation:

```
@set/p=␛[94mI'm <nul
```

Set the text colour to bright blue and write the initial `I'm`  without starting a new line.

```
@call:c Blue
```

Start with the word `Blue`.

```
:l
@for %%i in (Da Ba Dee Da Ba Die)do @call:c %%i
@goto l
```

Loop over the remaining words, and then repeat indefinitely.

```
:c
@ping 192.512 -n 1 -w 500>nul
@set/p=%1, <nul
```

Wait `500ms`, and then output the word with a trailing `,`  without starting a new line. `192.512` is a reserved IP address and it should not be possible to ping it, so the ping will time out after `0.5s` as desired.

Comment: @DLosc Thanks, fixed.